# Sorting cells of big numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I've created a big (say, 4000 X 4000) numpy matrix of floats. I'm sorting the cells of the matrix by the float value, producing a list of `(row,col,value)` tuples. This is my code (simplified):

```
def cells(matrix):
  shape = np.shape(matrix)
  for row in range(shape[0]):
    for col in range(shape[1]):
      yield (row, col, matrix[row,col])

# create a random matrix
matrix = np.random.randint(100, size=(4000,4000))
# sort the cells by value
sorted_cells = sorted(cells(matrix), key=lambda x: x[2])
```

I'm aware that doing the cell-by-cell yield is inefficient, but I don't know how iterate over `(row, col, value)` tuples of the matrix using pure numpy? **Maybe that is the real question**!

The problem with my current approach is that my computer totally dies during the sorting step.

It's not a problem if I do: `sorted(matrix.flatten())` which works fine, quite fast actually, but then I don't get the rows and cols...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is your friend here.  Instead of actually sorting the array it's given, it returns an array of integer indices that tell you how to reorder the array into sorted order.  Given that, you can apply the same sorting to the row and column values.

Here's some code:  first we generate a matrix;  here I'm using different numbers of rows and columns, so that we can easily check that the results are the right way around.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.random.randint(100, size=(4000, 5000))
>>> rows, cols = np.indices(matrix.shape)
```

Now use `argsort` to get the indices.

```
>>> reindex = np.argsort(matrix.flatten())
```

With those indices, we can recover the sorted matrix:

```
>>> matrix.flat[reindex]
array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 99, 99, 99])
```

*and* also the corresponding rows and columns.

```
>>> rows.flat[reindex]
array([2455, 2870, 1196, ...,   56,   56, 3618])
>>> cols.flat[reindex]
array([ 863, 1091, 4966, ..., 3959, 3887, 4833])
```

To verify the answer, let's check that the first row, column pair really does correspond to a matrix entry of `0`, and that the last row, column pair corresponds to `99`:

```
>>> r = rows.flat[reindex]
>>> c = cols.flat[reindex]
>>> matrix[r[0], c[0]]
0
>>> matrix[r[-1], c[-1]]
99
```

Edit:  as nye17's answer points out, the rows and columns can be recovered more directly from the `reindex` array.

```
>>> r, c = divmod(reindex, matrix.shape[1])
```

This all runs quite quickly (a few seconds for the sorting step).  I'd guess that the reason your original code is locking up the machine is that the lists you're generating take up a *lot* of memory;  by sticking with numpy arrays instead of lists and tuples, your memory overhead goes down significantly.

Comment: Instead of `mgrid`, wouldn't `rows, cols = np.indices(matrix.shape)` be a little cleaner?

Comment: @DSM It would indeed!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Mark beats me to the punch, but just my 2 cents

use a 2x2 matrix as example,

```
import numpy as np
# create a random matrix
matrix = np.random.randint(100, size=(2,2))
indice = np.argsort(matrix, axis=None)
# you can also use `divmod` per mark's version
ind_i = indice//2
ind_j = np.mod(indice, 2)
for i, j in zip(ind_i, ind_j) :
    print("%4d %4d %10.5f" % (i, j, matrix[i,j]))
```

it gives

```
1    0   12.00000
0    1   23.00000
1    1   59.00000
0    0   63.00000
```

Comment: Ah, `axis=None` is better than my `flatten` call.  Nice.

Comment: @MarkDickinson your mgrid apparently looks nicer than my naive //+mod calls ;-)

Comment: Just kidding, you have just saved me many hours of waiting, so thanks :-)

Comment: @PiminKonstantinKefaloukos ha, that was fine, not a bad joke at all, at least I enjoyed it a bit.